# not creating tree by rpart in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I'm new to R and rpart package. I want to create a tree using the following sample data.

My data set is similar to this
    mydata =

```
"","A","B","C","status"
"1",TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,"okay"
"2",TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,"okay"
"3",TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,"okay"
"4",TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,"notokay"
"5",FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,"notokay"
"6",FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,"notokay"
"7",FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,"okay"
"8",FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,"okay"
fit <- rpart(status ~ A + B + C, data = mydata, method = "class")
```

or 
I tried with different formulas and different methods in this. But always only the root node is produced. no plot possible. 
its showing

```
fit
n= 8 
node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
* denotes terminal node
1) root 8 3 okay (0.3750000 0.6250000) *
```

How to create the tree.? I need to show percentage of 
"okay" and "notokay" on each node. and i need to specify one out of A, B or C
for spliting and show the statistics

Comment: the function rpart only shows the root tree if the other variables add no predictive value to the model, in other words: you cant't differntiate between the different types of status using your variables, they are very bad predictors with no predictive power

Answer (score 1):

With the default settings of `rpart()` no splits are considered at all. The `minsplit` parameter is `20` by default (see `?rpart.control`) which is "the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order for a split to be attempted." So for your 8 observations no splitting is even considered.

If you are determined to consider splitting, then you could decrease the `minbucket` and/or `minsplit` parameters. For example

```
fit <- rpart(status ~ A + B + C, data = mydata,
  control = rpart.control(minsplit = 3))
```

produces the following tree:

[image: fitted rpart tree]

The display is created by

```
plot(partykit::as.party(fit), tp_args = list(beside = TRUE))
```

and the print output from `rpart` is:

```
n= 8 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 8 3 okay (0.3750000 0.6250000)  
  2) A=FALSE 4 2 notokay (0.5000000 0.5000000)  
    4) B=TRUE 2 0 notokay (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
    5) B=FALSE 2 0 okay (0.0000000 1.0000000) *
  3) A=TRUE 4 1 okay (0.2500000 0.7500000) *
```

Whether or not this is particularly useful is a different question though...